# Connection Reset after load test 150 concurrent user with scenario upload document 60 Mb

Tags: jmeter, connection-reset

I have the problem **Connection Reset** after load test 150 concurrent user with scenario **upload document 60 Mb**, but all files were successfully uploaded to the db.
Any help would greatly appreciated.

I need to get a 0% error rate in jmeter, because the document upload test results have been successfully uploaded to the database.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset" symptom is too broad, you need to investigate the root cause of that. For [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

additionally you can [enable Java debug logging for SSL/TLS connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and console output to determine what causes the connection reset.

If the issue isn't reproducible for the lower loads most probably it's due to the [bottleneck](https://www.educative.io/blog/performance-testing-101-bottlenecks) in the system under test